# JavaScript: Asynchronous function only in one case. How to access the result?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, web-services, asynchronous

I am developing a web application using Angular 8. I have a problem using JavaScript with an asynchronous function.
I have created a service that has a public method: this method examines a condition that can vary over time and in one case (*true*) it updates its data with a response to an **HTTP call**; in the other case (*false*) it returns the data it already has. Here is a code example:

```
private date; // My date

getMyDate() {

    if(my_boolean_condition) {

        this.http.post(this.myUrl, JSON.stringify(this.myInputData)).toPromise().then((data: any) => {
            this.date = data;

            return this.date;
        }

    } else {
        return this.date;
    }

}
```

I know perfectly that something is wrong with this code, but I don't understand what.
If a client (for example an Angular component) calls my `getMyDate()` method, the return value is however `undefined`.
What I want is for the method to always return a value different than `undefined`, whether it makes the HTTP call or doesn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: 1. Initialize date variable

Comment: 2. You dont need to stringify ur data in http.post

Comment: 3. You are not waiting for asynchronous call to be completed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first `return this.date;` is wrong because it's returning to a anonymous function passed to thenable. The correct way is to use async/await:

```
async getMyDate() {

    if(my_boolean_condition) {

        let response = await this.http.post(this.myUrl, JSON.stringify(this.myInputData)).toPromise();
        return response;
    } 

    return this.date;

}
```

**EDIT**

Check more: https://javascript.info/async-await